# Environment variables aren't availiable during SSH session to AWS ECS container

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have configured ECS containers. Everything works, however when I'm connecting to a container through SSH, there are no environment variables that are defined in a task definition.
Is there a way to persist them?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you ssh'd into the container, or a ec2 instance hosting the container?

Comment: The 1st option. I am using Fargate launch type.

Comment: @kozlone your django container is running an ssh daemon inside of it?

Comment: No, you can't persist environment variables that not present in the task definition. they will disappear when the process dies.

Comment: @jordanm >  your django container is running an ssh daemon inside of it?

Yes, it does for sure. 

> No, you can't persist environment variables that not present in the task definition. they will disappear when the process dies

Could you please provide details about it? I'm expecting hat all my env variable will be passed to a container, like `docker run ... -e ENV_VARIABLE` does it. So, is there any info about how ECS starts containers?

Comment: SSH starts a new session, with a fresh set of environment variables. `docker exec` does not do that, which you can only use if you are *not* running fargate.

Comment: @jordanm so, my guess was correct. Thank you :)

P. S.
You may want to submit the comment as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution.